# Bounds on percentile given z-score

Tags: probability, distributions, quantiles

Suppose we have a random variable $X$ that can take real values from 0 to 100, according to a distribution $f$, for which the expectation $E(X)$ and the variance $SD(X)^2$ are well defined and finite.

We define another variable $Z = \frac{X - E(X)}{SD(X)}$

Suppose I know that for a particular realisation of $X$, say $x$, the value of $Z$ is, say $z > k$.

Based on this information, and no other information on the distribution, can I say anything about which percentile $x$ is in?

If the distribution is known, then of course this is possible, but when the distribution is unknown, are there upper and lower limits on the possible percentile of $x$?

If not in general, then under some more, not too demanding conditions?

Comment: There's a variety of general bounds (both Chebyshev and Markov apply, for example), but the upper bound will also impose some restrictions; for some E(X) and SD(X) values that will have a strong effect, for others it will mean very little (e.g. if E(X) and SD(X) are both smallish, the bound at 100 will tend to contribute almost no additional information.

Comment: ... unless you look out many standard deviations. With additional information (unimodality, additional moments, etc), stronger bounds may be possible. Some one-sided bounds (which could be flipped to work from the other side) include: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Cantelli's_inequality and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality

Comment: As SD(X) approaches its upper bound (given $E(X)$ and the endpoints), the distribution becomes quite constrained.

Comment: There's also this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Bounded_variables

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b I'll try working with them

Comment: That last one is the place to focus, I think.